# How to install ati radeon 5650 hd graphic card

Tags: intel-graphics, hp, radeon

I want to install a GNU/Linux system on my laptop **HP dv7-4120ew**, because I've heard that 3d applications like Maya, Realflow or Houdini works here a lot better. Unfortunately, I can't install my **ATI Radeon 5650hd** graphic card.

I followed the instructions of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52JRCddtZLk&feature=plcp). After reboot the system I get the next error:

`The system is running in low graphic mode`.

Also running **fglrxinfo** in terminal gives me this errors:

```
X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request: 135 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request: 12
Current serial number in output stream: 12
```

Do you know how to fix this problem? Any solution allowing me to run 3d software will be good for me.

---

I have ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit version.

Comment: What OS do you have and which version is? e.g. Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Lucio see the edit, it's 12.04.

Comment: You might want to try this - http://askubuntu.com/a/126513/6005

Comment: Sorry, still having the same problem. I have also tried to reinstall my system and install older catalyst (12.4 and 12.6), but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ubuntu provides these drivers for you.
Open `System Settings`, and under `Hardware` look for `Additional Drivers`.

Edit: I never installed Catalyst centre on my computers, which both have the HD 5k series.

Comment: Erro, as I wrote, I need to run 3d applications on my laptop. Does open source drivers provide efficient support for 3d applications?